# Display all podcasts you're subscribed to on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts

Like a lot of people (or at least I imagine), I have iTunes set to sync all unplayed podcasts episodes to my iPhone, and also to delete the ones I have listened to. This obviously has the benefit that I don't clog up my hard drive with old episodes that I'm never likely to listen again, and I only have new episodes to choose from when I'm picking something to listen to.

I use iTunes on my home PC, but I'm almost always at work when I'm listening to podcasts. Since we have WiFi at work, if I become aware that a new episode has come out (via a blog post or whatever) I tend to just pick it up immediately, using the "get more episodes" link from within the podcast in question.

However I can't do this if I don't happen to have another episode of that same podcast already on the iPhone, as the "get more episodes" link obviously doesn't exist. I appreciate that I can still go via the iTunes store, and indeed thats what I end up doing, but I'd much prefer it if there was some way to have the iPod app display all of my subscriptions, regardless of whether there is currently an episode on the iPhone. I fear I know the answer, but does anybody know of any way to have it do this? Alternatively, is there better way around this than just keeping old episodes around?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you set iTunes to "get all new episodes", but then specifically download old episodes that would not be automatically downloaded, then the old episodes are not deleted when they are listened to. I think this would mean that you could just keep one old episode around for each of your podcasts and not have to worry about it disappearing, but it would still be marked as played so wouldn't be confused with new episodes.

I don't think there's currently any way to get a list of all subscribed podcasts on the iPhone itself.